# Soap XML response is composite (XML + html)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I am using wsdl soap service. I got the response string. I need to parse this composite response string. It consist of some html part in xml.

I tried NSXMLParser, TouchXML, SMXML but no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SEGMENTS>
<SEGMENT NAME="webcluster">
<RESULTPAGE>
<QUERYTRANSFORMS><QUERYTRANSFORM ACTION="NOP" CUSTOM="" MESSAGE="Original query" MESSAGEID="1" NAME="Original query" QUERY="AND(cdccomposite:string("company",annotation_class="user",mode="SIMPLEALL"), FILTER(and(cdccountry:"us",cdclanguage:"en")))"/>
</QUERYTRANSFORMS>
</RESULTPAGE>
</SEGMENT>
</SEGMENTS>
```

So can we parse such type of response (XML+HTML)..
Thanks,

Comment: and your question/problem is...? If you need example of xml parsing with some other tool (eg. TBXML) you may look at my question and answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123991/touchxml-xpath-error-probably-namespace-issue).

Comment: It looks like regular xml. There's problem with double quotes in `QUERYTRANSFORM`'s attribute `QUERY`, but the rest look pretty ordinary. What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: how can we parse this specific type of soap (xml + html) response.

Comment: There's no html here. You may use any tool for parsing, but I would recommend simple ones, like [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/). Why NSXMLParser, TouchXML, SMXML failed?

Comment: No, this soap response also consist html..  http://pastebin.com/AEwiqwRm